# Ruby On Rails - Securing Downloads Area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I upload files to my server and thus have clients/customers download these files. How may I restrict the access of the file?

Such as, if I upload a file to www.domain.com/files/download.zip

And if the user has correct permissions he can download the file, but what if the user knows the direct link to the file itself?

Cause I can imagine how to not show the link to the user on the site if they don't have permission to see the link, but how do I prevent someone from just typing in the direct URL of the location of the file to download the file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put those uploads in `/public` if you want to secure them. Keep them in a folder outside of your web root, then have a controller that uses [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file) to allow them to download the file if authorized.

Comment: but what if I want them to store in public so that front end can access them easily, how ?