# Is everyone allowed to access rails public folder via URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, asset-pipeline, carrierwave, public

When assets like images or files are in the rails public directory with asset pipeline enabled, is everyone allowed to access them through URL?

I am asking this because now I am learning about implementing File Uploading through Carrierwave with the help of the book, Rails 4 in Action, and it says the files should be moved outside the public folder for access control.

If assets are in the public folder, does it mean that we can't do access control?

Comment: everything inside public is accessed by the server..such as images,js and css files..so you can easily access it by localhost:80.com/images/ring.gif or http://myapp.herokuapp.com/images/ring.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any one can access the contents of public folder through URL.

Ref:

[Are files in public folder accessible to outside world? - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268580/are-files-in-public-folder-accessible-to-outside-world-rails)

Comment: how to access the file inside public folder? Ive added upload folder to store some images.

Comment: Please refer this

https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/what-is-the-url-for-my-public-folder/159564